# react antd Loading Branch dropdown after selecting company drop down in table inline edit

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a table which displays the list of company related information, while we are trying to edit a company related information in table, Changing the company id, needs to fetch and populate branch dropdown associated with the changed company value

Here is the code for company dropdown and branch dropdown.

```
var companyData =[];
var branchData =[];

axios.get('http://localhost:8000/masters/selectcompany').then((result) => {
    companyData = result.data;
)};

const handleChangebranchid = (e) => {    
  var value = e;
  axios.get('http://localhost:8000/masters/branchselect?companyid='+value).then((result) => {
    branchData = result.data;
   
})}
 
const BranchSelect = () => {
  return (
    <Select
    placeholder="branch"
     onChange={(value) => handleChange(value)}
    allowClear
    >
      {branchData.map(branch =>
      <Option value={branch.value}>{branch.value}</Option>
    )}
    </Select>
  )
}

     
const CompSelect = () => {
  return (
    <Select
    placeholder="companyid"
    onChange={handleChangebranchid}
    allowClear
  >{companyData.map(company =>
    <Option value={company.value}>{company.name}</Option>
  )}
  </Select>
  )
}
})

return(
      <Form.Item
        style={{
          margin: 0,
        }}
        name='company_id'
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: `Company is required.`,
          },
        ]}
      >
        <CompSelect />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item
        style={{
          margin: 0,
        }}
        name='branch_id'
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: `Branch is required.`,
          },
        ]}
      >
        <BranchSelect />
      </Form.Item>
)
```

Please anyone help me to get rid from this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`e` refers to the entire event in `handleChangebranchid`. You have to use `e.target.value` to execute the code

change the following

```
const handleChangebranchid = (e) => {    
  var value = e;
  axios.get('http://localhost:8000/masters/branchselect?companyid='+value).then((result) => {
    branchData = result.data;
   
})}
```

to

```
const handleChangebranchid = (e) => {    
  var value = e.target.value;
  axios.get('http://localhost:8000/masters/branchselect?companyid='+value).then((result) => {
    branchData = result.data;
   
})}
```